# transaction() doesn't increment @@TRANCOUNT?

Tags: sql-server, database, qt, transactions

MS SQL SERVER 2008. Qt + ODBC.

I'm trying to rollback some changes (which were made in inner) in database by rolling back transaction of the highest level. But it's looks like my second db.transaction() call doesn't increment @@TRANCOUNT and first commit (inner) close transaction completly. Because of this, next rollback command in outer transaction level just ignored.

Some example. Commented strings display @@TRANCOUNT received from DB after eachoperation:

```
db.transaction();                                       //@@TRANCOUNT = 0
query->exec("INSERT INTO TestOnly (Value) VALUES('1')");//@@TRANCOUNT = 1
db.transaction();                                       //@@TRANCOUNT = 1
query->exec("INSERT INTO TestOnly (Value) VALUES('2')");//@@TRANCOUNT = 1
db.commit();                                            //@@TRANCOUNT = 0
query->exec("INSERT INTO TestOnly (Value) VALUES('3')");//@@TRANCOUNT = 0
db.rollback();                                          //@@TRANCOUNT = 0
```

Test code:

```
...
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC3");
...
query = new QSqlQuery(db);
...

bool ok;
ok = db.transaction(); qDebug() << "Start transaction" << " result = " << ok << "; errorText: " << db.lastError().text();
PrintTranCount(); //0

query->exec("INSERT INTO TestOnly (Value) VALUES('1')");
PrintTranCount(); //1

ok = db.transaction(); qDebug() << "Start transaction" << " result = " << ok << "; errorText: " << db.lastError().text();
PrintTranCount(); //2

query->exec("INSERT INTO TestOnly (Value) VALUES('2')");
PrintTranCount(); //3

ok = db.commit(); qDebug() << "Commit transaction" << " result = " << ok << "; errorText: " << db.lastError().text();
PrintTranCount(); //4

query->exec("INSERT INTO TestOnly (Value) VALUES('3')");
PrintTranCount(); //5

ok = db.rollback();  qDebug() << "Rollback transaction" << " result = " << ok << "; errorText: " << db.lastError().text();
PrintTranCount(); //6
```

Debug output:

```
Start transaction  result =  true ; errorText:  " "  
Transaction Count   0: 0  
Transaction Count   1: 1   
Start transaction  result =  true ; errorText:  " "   
Transaction Count   2: 1   
Transaction Count   3: 1   
Commit transaction  result =  true ; errorText:  " "  
Transaction Count   4: 0  
Transaction Count   5: 0   
Rollback transaction  result =  true ; errorText:  " "  
Transaction Count   6: 0
```

PrintTranCount() function:

```
static int Num = 0;
query->exec("SELECT @@TRANCOUNT");query->first();
qDebug() << "Transaction Count  "<< Num << ": " <<query->value(0).toInt();
Num++;
```

Is there any reason why the transaction counter (@@TRANCOUNT) does not increase to 2 after second transaction? I did not correctly understand the idea of transaction counter? Or there are problems with database/driver settings? Maybe there are some errors in my example code that i missed?

I will be gratefull for any hints. Sorry for google translate :)

Comment: There are no nested transaction in SQL Server in sense that commit of any "inner" transaction commits nothing (only increase @@trancount) and any "inner" rollback roll backs all.

Comment: Please read here: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/

Comment: Sorry, i didn't describe problem properly. In my case (with '1' '2' '3' inserts described above) there aren't any operation that was rolled back at all.  According to an article from your comment, an external rollback should cancel the operation commited in internal transaction. But this does not happen. I have all three rows in TestOnly table. I decided to ask about the transaction counter right away, because it looks like the database does not start an internal transaction at all.

Comment: I don't know your programming language but if you use T-SQL and write 3 inserts like this: INSERT INTO TestOnly (Value) VALUES('1'); INSERT INTO TestOnly (Value) VALUES('2');INSERT INTO TestOnly (Value) VALUES('3') there will be THREE transactions, SQL Server operates in auto commit mode

Comment: To get all of them in ONE transaction you should explicitly OPEN transaction: BEGIN TRAN INSERT INTO TestOnly (Value) VALUES('1'); INSERT INTO TestOnly (Value) VALUES('2');INSERT INTO TestOnly (Value) VALUES('3'); COMMIT

Comment: ...And if you do  BEGIN TRAN INSERT INTO TestOnly (Value) VALUES('1'); INSERT INTO TestOnly (Value) VALUES('2');INSERT INTO TestOnly (Value) VALUES('3'); ROLLBACK all 3 inserts will be rolled back

Comment: I have some "small" functions in my programm. Each is framed with  its own begin/end transaction command. I neen to run this functions as a parts of some big operation one after another. Sometimes, i need to rollback all changes made in transactions of "small" functions. For this purpose there is one outer transaction  wich includes all "small" operations. But rolling back that (outer) transaction didn't cancel changes made in "small" functions. I cannot remove inner transactions from "small" operations, cuz they can be called independently and contain their own suboperations.

Comment: >>>But rolling back that (outer) transaction didn't cancel changes made in "small" functions.<<< This means that there is NO outer transactions, and all your "inner" transactions are not nested at all. From your "inner" transactions do print/select @@trancount. If it's 1, there is only one transaction, inner transaction

Comment: Back to square one. That was my first question in this post:(  Why my example doesn't start inner transaction and @@trancount does not rise above 1? What i'm doing wrong?
It's leterally painfull for me to use english and I'm sorry about forcing you to read all this mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Everything was resolved by viewing the source code**:

db.transaction() doesn't send any "begin tran" command to database (at least with ODBC driver). This function only change commit mode to "[manual commit mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/manual-commit-mode)". After that, first db.commit() confirms all changes (by sending "SQLEndTran" command) and change mode back to "auto commit mode" again.

To use "nested"(not really nested) transactions with @@TRANCOUNT it is enough to manually send "tran begin"/"commit"/"rollback" commands to database. In my example:

```
query->exec("begin tran");                              //@@TRANCOUNT = 1
query->exec("INSERT INTO TestOnly (Value) VALUES('1')");//@@TRANCOUNT = 1
query->exec("begin tran");                              //@@TRANCOUNT = 2
query->exec("INSERT INTO TestOnly (Value) VALUES('2')");//@@TRANCOUNT = 2
query->exec("commit");                                  //@@TRANCOUNT = 1
query->exec("INSERT INTO TestOnly (Value) VALUES('3')");//@@TRANCOUNT = 1
query->exec("rollback");                                //@@TRANCOUNT = 0
```